# How to apply the default Firefox style for input type range?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

When I load input type range in different browsers such as Edge and Chrome I get different look and feel for this input.

Is there a way to apply the Firefox's styling for Chrome and Edge?

```html
    <input type="range" id="volume" name="volume" min="0" max="11" />
```

[image]

Comment: You would have to manually do it in CSS, as browsers do not store other browsers' styling.